# REST API soft errors and warnings

Tags: python, api, rest, flask, warnings

I'm designing a REST API, and I have an endpoint with a relatively flexible input.

Basically, it would be ideal to have a 48x48 array, but so long as it is an array, we can resize it to the correct size in a relatively intelligent way.

The resize operation isn't very costly, but I feel like the user should know that whatever input is being given is non-ideal, but I want this error message to be noninvasive.

I think this should still have an HTTP code of 200, but I could be persuaded otherwise.

Is there any accepted way of including metadata with a REST response?

I haven't found anything like this, but I feel like it can't be that strange a request.

For reference, using `flask`, and example code is below:

```
class Function(MethodView):
    def post(self):
        post_array = np.array(json.loads(request.form['data']))
        if post_array.shape != (48, 48):
            post_array = post_array.resize((48,48)) # Add some warning
        return process(post_array)
```

Comment: Perhaps your response should always include an `errors` or `warnings` field (which is normally empty).

Comment: @JonathonReinhart That actually is a pretty nice and elegant solution... If you want to add some example code for future googlers that would be a great answer.

Comment: I've never implemented such an API, but I know I've consumed one at some point. Trying to remember what it was...

Answer (score 0):

As Jonathon Reinhart points out, including the warning as part of the response would be ideal. It should return 200 status for sure.

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify # jsonify is helpful for ensuring json in response

class Function(MethodView):
    def post(self):
        # create a response body dict with an empty warnings list
        response_body = {
                'warnings': [],
                'process_result': None
            }

        # create a guard in case POST request body is not JSON   
        if request.json:
            post_array = np.array(json.loads(request.form['data']))
            if post_array.shape != (48, 48):
                post_array = post_array.resize((48,48))
                # add a warning to the response body
                warning = {'data_shape_warning': 'the supplied data was not 48 x 48'}
                response_body['warnings'].append(warning)
            # compute the process and add the result to the response body
            result = process(post_array)
            response_body['process_result'] = result
            return response_body, 200

        # action to take if the POST body is not JSON
        else:
            warning = {'data_format_warning': 'POST request data was not JSON'}
            response_body['warnings'].append(warning)
            return jsonify(response_body), 200
```